# What does it mean “G-d knows you by name”?

Tags: jesus, book-of-life

Beginning with Moises in Exodus 33:17, preceding to king David in Psalms,  in teaching of Christ in John 10 and in Revelation 20:15, Bible declares very plainly- G-d knows His people by their names. David knew G-d knows his name in Pslms 91:14, 139:1 and 127:24. How do you know he knows you? So far searching for an assurance He knows my name, Bible doesn’t give us any specific verses in which we can say “here is the key” Not our belief in G-d assure it because James 2:19, nighter our deeds in His name Matthew 7:22-23. I should say I’d be pretty devastating to come to the Throne and He says “Away from me I never knew you” So there is my question, how through the scriptures I can know He knows my name?

Comment: There are at least two very good reasons for giving Bible verses in your question.  First, it prevents anyone from making assumptions - after all, we are not mind readers!  Second, the whole point of Biblical Hermeneutics is to examine Scripture, not opinions.  Please take our tour and consider editing your question in order to attract answers: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Ok gotcha, will edit in a sec

Answer (score 3):

This Hebrew idiom is one of numerous such that demonstrates the personal nature of the God's relationship with each person.  Here is a sample:

- One of the first titles given to Jesus was "Immanuel = God with us" (Matt 1:23), as opposed to the distant nature of false gods (Dan 2:11)
- The LORD knows people's thoughts (Ps 94:11)
- God numbers the very hairs of our head (Luke 7:12:7, Matt10:30)
- God knows the way I take (Job 23:10)
- God knows me by name (Ps 91:14, 139:1, 127:24)
- God knows the secrets of the heart (Ps 44:2)
- The LORD knows our daily struggles (Ps 37:18 GW)
- God's people are called by His name (2 Chron 7:14, Isa 43:7, 65:1, Acts 11:26)
- God's people are called His treasured possession (Ex 19:5, 6, Deut 7:6, 14:2, 26:18, Ps 135:4, Mal 3:17, 1 Peter 2:9, etc)
- God eternally loves His people and has drawn them with loving kindness (Jer 31:3, Ps 36:7, 89:33, 25:10, etc)

Therefore, the fact that God knows us by name is entirely expected.

Answer (score 3):

Names in the Bible represent more than just a moniker, more than just a sound designed to catch our attention.  Biblically [names encompass all that an entity is](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/why-names-are-so-important-in-the-bible-and-so-is-yours/101095.htm) including origin, character, and direction.  This is why there is such power in the name of the Lord; because the Name represents all that He is.

> Then Moses said to God, “If I come to the people of Israel and say to them, ‘The God of your fathers has sent me to you,’ and they ask me, ‘What is his name?’ what shall I say to them?” God said to Moses, “I AM THAT I AM.” And he said, “Say this to the people of Israel: ‘I AM has sent me to you.’” - Exodus 3:13-14

This name emphasizes God's power in self existence (I exists so that I may be in existence) and it also points out that He alone has the authority to assign Himself a name because naming requires dominion and nothing has dominion over El Elyon (the Most High God).

> Gen 1:28  And God blessed them. And God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply and fill the earth and subdue it, and **have dominion over** the fish of the sea and over the birds of the heavens and over every living thing that moves on the earth.”
>
> Gen 2:19  Now out of the ground the LORD God had formed every beast of the field and every bird of the heavens and brought them to the man to see what he would call them. And **whatever the man called every living creature, that was its name.**

God has also revealed many [other names for Himself](https://www.hebrew4christians.com/Names_of_G-d/El/el.html).  These names highlight aspects of His being and can carry names because, just like God Himself, His attributes are also infinite and eternal:

> > El Roi - the God who sees,   El Shaddai - the God who is sufficient,   El Elyon - the most high God,    Yahweh Jireh - God who provides,
> >     Yahweh Rophe - God who heals,   Yahweh Makedesh - God who sanctifies

In this vein, when it is said that God knows each person's name, what is being communicated is that God knows absolutely every thing about each one including but not limited to:

Span of earthly life - Job 14:5-7, Psalm 39:4

Inner thoughts - Psalm 139:4, Hebrews 4:12

Ultimate dispensation - Romans 9:20-24

And [He has always known](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208%3A29-30&version=ESV) everything about each one, always will, and cannot be said to learn anything about us as we progress through life.

What does it mean, then, that Jesus will someday say to some,

> “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven.  On that day many will say to me, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many mighty works in your name?’  And then will I declare to them, **‘I never knew you**; depart from me, you workers of lawlessness.’ - Matthew 7:21-23

The answer lies in a second meaning of 'Knew" which is not intellectual knowledge but relational knowledge.  This knowledge is intimate, personal, requires the participation of both parties (as in 'Adam knew his wife Eve and she conceived and bore a son') and is highlighted in the verse above by "but the the one who does the will of my Father".

In order to move from the position of one who is 'intellectually known' by God to the position of one who is 'relationally known' by God one must do the will of the Father in Heaven.  In order to do the will of the Father in Heaven one must first become a child of that Father.  In order to become a child of the Father in Heaven one must be [born another time](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A5-6&version=ESV), not just physically but spiritually.

> But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God, who were born, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God. - John 1:12-13

God, who knows each one in complete and perfect detail, has provided an access point to transition from mere creation to child of God and this access point is to [believe in the one that He has sent](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A29&version=ESV).  This is the answer to your question: "how through the scriptures I can know He knows my name?"  It is through the Scriptures that we can know the Lord and Savior Jesus Christ and, through that [singular name](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%204%3A12&version=ESV), we can know God as Father and be [known by God](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%208%3A3&version=ESV) as His child.

> See what kind of love the Father has given to us, that we should be called children of God; and so we are. The reason why the world does not know us is that it did not know him. Beloved, we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet appeared; but we know that when he appears we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is. - 1 John 3:1-2